# MySQL - Fulltext Index Search Issue

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Two rows in the my database have the following data:

```
brand       | product                     | style
=================================================
Doc Martens | Doc Martens 1460 Boots      | NULL
NewBalance  | New Balance WR1062 SG Width | NULL
```

Mininum word length is set to **3**, and a **FULLTEXT** index is created across all the three columns above.

When I run a search for IS BOOLEAN matches for **+doc** in the index, I get the first row returned as a result. When I search for **+new**, I get no results.

Can someone explain why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It called **FULLTEXT** because of it indexes whole words. so for searching words started with "New" you have to put "astrisk" sign in the end:

```
MATCH (`brand`) AGAINST ('new*')
```

More detailed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)